# How to find maximum values in DataFrame and return a resulting DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame looking partly like this:

```
df_all_q
Out[43]: 
    Qtot      Ptot  Q_G1  Q_G2      P_G1      P_G2
0    0.0  0.000000   0.0   0.0  0.000000  0.000000
1    5.0  0.576190   0.0   5.0  0.000000  0.576190
2    5.0  0.581900   5.0   0.0  0.581900  0.000000
3   10.0  1.152380   0.0  10.0  0.000000  1.152380
4   10.0  1.163800  10.0   0.0  1.163800  0.000000
5   10.0  1.158090   5.0   5.0  0.581900  0.576190
6   15.0  1.805147  15.0   0.0  1.805147  0.000000
7   15.0  1.734280   5.0  10.0  0.581900  1.152380
8   15.0  1.739990  10.0   5.0  1.163800  0.576190
9   15.0  1.569220   0.0  15.0  0.000000  1.569220
10  20.0  2.381337  15.0   5.0  1.805147  0.576190
11  20.0  2.151120   5.0  15.0  0.581900  1.569220
12  20.0  2.466860  20.0   0.0  2.466860  0.000000
13  20.0  1.782640   0.0  20.0  0.000000  1.782640
14  20.0  2.316180  10.0  10.0  1.163800  1.152380
15  25.0  2.713030   0.0  25.0  0.000000  2.713030
16  25.0  2.364540   5.0  20.0  0.581900  1.782640
17  25.0  3.043050  20.0   5.0  2.466860  0.576190
18  25.0  3.111990  25.0   0.0  3.111990  0.000000
19  25.0  2.957527  15.0  10.0  1.805147  1.152380
20  25.0  2.733020  10.0  15.0  1.163800  1.569220
```

Now I need to create another DataFrame with the maximum value of Ptot for each Qtot, like this:

```
df_result
Out[45]: 
    Qtot      Ptot  Q_G1  Q_G2      P_G1  P_G2
0    0.0  0.000000   0.0   0.0  0.000000   0.0
2    5.0  0.581900   5.0   0.0  0.581900   0.0
4   10.0  1.163800  10.0   0.0  1.163800   0.0
6   15.0  1.805147  15.0   0.0  1.805147   0.0
12  20.0  2.466860  20.0   0.0  2.466860   0.0
18  25.0  3.111990  25.0   0.0  3.111990   0.0
```

I guess this should be possible quite easily, however I'm stuck.

Comment: What have you tried here?

Comment: `df.groupby('Qtot', as_index=False).max()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `.groupby` method. It works similar `groupby` in sql and returns a dataframe.
After grouping, you define operations to the groups. There is the `max` operation for the `Ptot` (as you want it) and you can return `mean` for the others.
Other option is returning just the `Ptot` column and then merge the resulting dataframe with the old one.

```
df_all_q.groupby('Qtot').agg({'Ptot': 'max', 'Q_G1': 'mean',
'Q_G2': 'mean', 'P_G1': 'mean', 'P_G2': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

So, by parts:
`.groupby` groups all Qtot with same values
`.add` sets the aggregating function for each column
`.reset_index` makes the `Qtot` a ordinary column instead of the index of the new dataframe

If, for instance, you want that the `P_G1` column on the results is the `max` instead of the `mean` you can substitute the `'max'` by `'mean'`.
Common aggregation functions inlcudes `sum`, `max`, `min`, `mean`, `size` and `first`. Full list can be found in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)